# Allow User to Shut Down XP from the Command Line

Tags: windows, windows-xp, group-policy

Using Remote Desktop (RDP/Terminal Services), I can't select Shutdown/Reboot from the Windows XP start menu, so I generally have to open a terminal and enter `shutdown -s -t 0` to initiate an immediate shutdown.

But, for a new system, I have added a non-administrative user to the *Remote Desktop Users* group, and when I try to issue a shutdown command as that user, the command returns the following error:

> A required privilege is not held by the client.

I verified that my user has the "Shutdown" privilege in the Security Settings (in the **Group Policy** editor: *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment*, the **Shut down the system** policy). What other privilege do I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the **Shut down the system** right, also ensure the user has the right to the **Force shutdown from a remote system** policy.

In my case, I added the *Remote Desktop Users* group to that policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the GUI. It's not where you would normally find it though. When connected to Remote Desktop there is an additional menu item, usually name something like "Windows Security". I can't recall the exact wording on XP. In there you'll find your usual shutdown, logoff, etc.

Comment: Interesting. Where would I find this item? It doesn't jump out at me when I'm browsing through the Start Menu.

Comment: I'm not in a position to do this with XP at the moment, so can't offer you a screen shot, but when you click on the Start Menu there should be the new item near the Control Panel item, or just below it from memory.

Comment: Oh, I do see that! I've never paid any attention to that before! On the XP Start Menu (not "Classic"), I have a **Windows Security** entry below **Control Panel** and **Run...**. Selecting this brings me to a window like XP's "Lock" window, and from there I can select **Shut Down...**, among other options.

Comment: It's distinctly less than intuitive. ;)